# Do I need to install another Bonding bus bar in the disconnect?

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

In Texas (CenterPoint Energy) from the meter can to the disconnect, I have three wires, HOT, HOT and Neutral.   In the disconnect I need to connect the Neutral to the ground however the Neutral bus bar only has an opening for one 4 ought wire. Do I need to purchase another ground bar and install it in the disconnect and Bond them together?  I know they need to be bonded there, how do I physically do it?[image]

Comment: Is the disconnect service rated? If it is, it should have means to bond the neutral to the container. Look for a bonding screw.  But in any event yes, this would be considered a service, therefore the neutral and the ground must become one.  remember from here on, you need 4-wires.

Comment: I'm still stuck on whether the disconnect is service rated.  If it is not you may be in trouble.  But if the inspector will buy off on it just purchase a chair lug the right size, scratch the paint, and bolt it to the container.

Comment: That is an excellent question!  I will check and see if it is service rated. Also I cut the fourth wire and thought it was not needed. Re-dug the hole 5' deep and ran all four wires again. Is it permissible to use a Polaris Insulated connector in the disconnect to bond the Neutral and Ground?

Comment: I would use a chair lug also, how high up is the meter base ? I am sure it is two high up for the utilities in my neck of the woods, but that could be because my phone is tough to make out most photos.

Comment: Your vision is very good! Yes it is too far up for right now, however all the ground is being brought up and it will 5.5 feet above the ground and the disconnect will be higher then 36".

Comment: Where I come from you need a ground rod here, a single ground buss and 4-wires to the next panel, which should also have a ground rod, and separated grounds and neutrals.

Comment: This area is not my forte, but that does not look like a service panel to me.  It looks like a switch inline with the service wiring, and the underground wire is still your service drop. Ergo the neutral-ground bond (singular) belongs in the main panel, the one with the main breaker, presumably inside your home...

Comment: Rather than a Polaris connector I would recommend and I think the inspector would want is a two barrel or three barrel chair type lug.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question. Yes you do need to add another ground bar to bond the neutral and the ground wire at the first means of disconnect and you will need to attach your ground you brought in under ground. Also as @Tyson has pointed out you will need a driven ground rod at the disconnect. What everyone else is saying is that you will need to isolate the neutral from the ground at any panel down stream. As far as what method you use to bond this disconnect you probably want to run that through the AHJ. I like @Paul Logan's advice but you need to use a four barrel lug. Neutral in, neutral out, grounding electrode conductor, and grounding wire out.

As far as I can see the disconnect is service rated. It's just a fused disconnect instead of a main or enclosed breaker.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I know it's rated at 200 amp, however today I'll take a picture of the sticker and make sure it's a service disconnect before I go any further. Will purchase a quadruple panel lug if this panel is okay to keep. And install the ground rod. Thanks again for your help. And make sure the Ground and Neutral are isolated downstream.

Comment: Thanks again for all the advice. I'm doing exactly as everyone has suggested. Installing the 4 lug chair Lug, ground rod and Isolating ground and neutral after the first point of disconnect.  Checked the labels and it says can be  used as service disconnect so should be good to go I have added pictures of the labels at http://www.ddprent.com/service-disconnect.html   but I think were on the right track with everyone's help. Thanks again.